# How do I prevent emacs from overwriting files without warning?

Tags: emacs

On two different occasions, I have overwritten important files with emacs, without even realizing it until later. This happens because various commands (specifically `org-agenda-write` and `org-export`) will simply replace an existing file without a warning that a file with that name already exists. Is there way to configure emacs so that this won't happen?

Comment: Can you give examples of commands that overwrite files?

Comment: Yes, please provide steps to repro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org-agenda-write` uses `write-file` to save your agenda. This function, when called from a program, will over-write existing files without confirmation. `write-file` is buried pretty deep inside `org-agenda-write`, and modifying it directly is likely to cause surprising bugs elsewhere in Emacs. However, you can wrap `org-agenda-write` in an around advice. This is a neat way to add a check for the existence of the file, and alert the user before over-writing it.

```lisp
(defadvice org-agenda-write (around my-file-check)
  "Check if a file exists before writing the agenda to it."
  (if (file-exists-p file)
      (if (y-or-n-p (format "Overwrite %s?" file))
          ad-do-it)
    ad-do-it))

(ad-activate 'org-agenda-write)
```

This might qualify as a bug in `org-agenda-write`, and if you ask nicely on the orgmode mailing list they might be convinced to make this check the default behaviour.

The file writing behaviour of `org-export` looks a little more involved, and may draw on external programs to complete. Still, you could probably use a similar wrapper on that if you like.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this code a try. I take it that if there is no global solution that would apply to any function that tries to overwrite an existing file without warning?

Comment: You could advise `write-file`. But it's risky to mess with basic functions like that, as write-file is used by a lot of other code. Most file-writing functions already check for overwriting. If they don't its probably a bug that should be fixed. That's the best global solution.